# How do I create a sample XML file from a WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to allow users of my application to call a WCF service of their choosing.
I'd like them to provide my app with a WSDL address, and then my system would provide a sample soap message that they can then manipulate and send.

The problem is that I cannot find a practical way to generate the soap message.

Because my users probably won't have Visual Studio or Windows SDK's, I can't use XSD.exe or WSDL.exe. Also directing the user to SoapUI is not really professional enough.

My preference is not to write this code from scratch as it's probably a lot of work, and this isn't the main feature of my app.  I'm happy to pay for a third party library or WPF control if only I could find one.

Does anyone know of such a library, control, or tutorial?

Thanks